# React native ListView detect programmatically scrolling over normal scrolling

Tags: listview, react-native, scroll, scrollview

I'm using the [onscroll](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview.html#onscroll) props inside my ListView to detect any scroll, I also have a button that make you scroll to a specific position inside the listview using `this.refs.listView.scrollTo(..)`, however I want to distinguish between these 2 types of scrolling ( finger scrolling vs programmatically scrolling ) because each time I scroll using the button the `onscroll` also fired (I don't want that to happen).

So is there a way to distinguish between these scrolling types?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a built in way to do this but you could set a boolean when the button is pressed and use that in your onScroll handler to determine if you should execute your code.
You should be able to get the y position in your onScroll and when it equals the position that your button press programmatically scrolled to, you could reset the boolean.

Comment: Thanks that's exactly why I did, but I think it's not a good way? I prefer a built in way, maybe using a property in the event fired from onscroll method.